# Insert formulas in cells until blank row

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I wrote this formula and it works just fine within a regular worksheet but I have no idea how to put it into VBA:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;MW!$A$2:$X$1000;6;FALSE));IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;RZ!$A$2:$X$1000;6;FALSE));IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;FK!$A$2:$X$1000;6;FALSE));IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;MK!$A$2:$X$1000;6;FALSE));VLOOKUP(A2;AS!$A$2:$X$1000;6;FALSE);VLOOKUP(A2;MK!$A$2:$X$1000;6;FALSE));VLOOKUP(A2;FK!$A$2:$X$1000;6;FALSE));VLOOKUP(A2;RZ!$A$2:$X$1000;6;FALSE));VLOOKUP(A2;MW!$A$2:$X$1000;6;FALSE))
```

However, I'd like to make this process automated. It would have to put this line in every cell in column F until it encounters a blank row. I am aware that there would have to be some sort of iteration for A2 part (for cell F5 function it would be A5 and so on).

Comment: I would start by taking advantage of the [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) introduced in XL2007 and shorten the formula to `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;MW!$A$2:$X$1000;6;FALSE); 
      IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;RZ!$A$2:$X$1000;6;FALSE); 
            IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;FK!$A$2:$X$1000;6;FALSE); 
                  IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;MK!$A$2:$X$1000;6;FALSE); ""))))`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Range("F2:F" & Cells(1, 6).End(xlDown).Row).Formula = _
   "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;MW!$A$2:$X$1000;6;FALSE));IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;RZ!$A$2:$X$1000;6;FALSE));IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;FK!$A$2:$X$1000;6;FALSE));IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;MK!$A$2:$X$1000;6;FALSE));VLOOKUP(A2;AS!$A$2:$X$1000;6;FALSE);VLOOKUP(A2;MK!$A$2:$X$1000;6;FALSE));VLOOKUP(A2;FK!$A$2:$X$1000;6;FALSE));VLOOKUP(A2;RZ!$A$2:$X$1000;6;FALSE));VLOOKUP(A2;MW!$A$2:$X$1000;6;FALSE)"
```

Comment: I am afraid it would work only for the first row. Some kind of iteration would be required for this function to work for anything below.

Comment: Alright, I'll do that as soon as possible. Could you provide the rest of the code? I am not too familiar with VBA. :s

Comment: @Macro Man code is complete. You have to just put it between ` Sub Macro() and End Sub . Google to see VBA examples.

Comment: @M.W. see above comment, if you don't understand VBA I would suggest not to use it until you do understand - changes done in code cannot be undone.

Comment: I am afraid that it doesn't seem to work. I keep getting Runtime error 1004 doing it your way.                                                                         To what I said before: I usually do understand the code but I am unable to write one myself yet. In that way I am not experienced enough and it is the reason why I am seeking your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I moved a step further. 
Unfortunately your code doesn't work (runtime error) but I managed to put something else together.

```
Sub Macro1()

Range("F2").Select
Range("F2:F4000").Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;MW!$A$2:$X$1000;6;FALSE));IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;RZ!$A$2:$X$1000;6;FALSE));IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1;FK!$A$2:$X$1000;6;FALSE));IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;MK!$A$2:$X$1000;6;FALSE));VLOOKUP(A2;AS!$A$2:$X$1000;6;FALSE);VLOOKUP(A2;MK!$A$2:$X$1000;6;FALSE));VLOOKUP(A1;FK!$A$2:$X$1000;6;FALSE));VLOOKUP(A2;RZ!$A$2:$X$1000;6;FALSE));VLOOKUP(A2;MW!$A$2:$X$1000;6;FALSE))"
End Sub
```

It does work perfectly well if I enter =sum(B2+B3). With =if it ceases to work after I enter first "(".

Any ideas?